# Meaning of 'to mother someone'

Tags: meaning

Could someone explain me please exact meaning of phrase '**to mother someone**' and in which cases I can use it. As I managed to figure it out, means: to take care of someone or to look after of someone. Am I right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To mother: to act as mother to, as in nourishing and protecting. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mother.  ***What exactly is unclear about this term?***

Comment: I'm just a bit uncertain about its context, for example: `Mother her, she is ill` Is it referred only to her mother, or another person can also 'mother' her?

Comment: It means ***act as a mother*** so the person in question who is acting as a mother can very likely be a different  person.

Comment: @Josh61 I know a guy who is a squaddie in the Royal Engineers, and the fearsome-looking sergeant they had on some recent infantry exercises was known as *mum* to all the chaps in the platoon. Whether he actually *mothered* them or not I didn't ask.

Comment: Yes, it's to act as someone's mother, literally or (more often) figuratively. This can mean either taking care of them or being overly indulgent of them, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "to mother (someone)" literally means "to take on a mother's responsibilties as one's own".

Dictionary.com provides some good examples and definitions on the term:

**[mother](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mother?s=t)**

*verb (used with object)*

- to be the mother of; give origin or rise to.
- to acknowledge oneself the author of; assume as one's own.
- to care for or protect like a mother; act maternally toward.